# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror can't load amd 64-bit .dll ia 32-bit

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my project on Eclipse. It worked fine on the computer I developed it on, but when I imported it to my laptop it didn't work.

This question has already been asked elsewhere on this site, and the main cause of this problem seems to be environment variables not set correctly. But I have checked them, and they seem to be correct, unless I have missed something?

I do have the 64 bit JRE installed. Also, why does a jndi exception come up?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AjaxSpringMVC2' did not find a matching property.
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ajaxjqjsbowling' did not find a matching property.
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 850 ms
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardServletEnvironment.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 29, 2013 11:42:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /ajaxjqjsbowling threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardServletEnvironment.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 29, 2013 11:42:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\JohnH\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AjaxSpringMVC2\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6888 ms
Apr 29, 2013 11:42:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardServletEnvironment.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 29, 2013 11:42:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardServletEnvironment.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 29, 2013 11:42:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ajaxjqjsbowling] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardServletEnvironment.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Are you sure you have a 64 bit processor on your laptop? This is a DLL load fail and has nothing to do with JRE. It looks like you are trying to run 64 bit tomcat on a 32 bit machine. Get a 32 bit tomcat on your laptop and try running your application.

Comment: Found the issue; My version of eclipse is 32-bit. Oversight on my part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with my tomcat which is embeded in xampp. I was getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tcnative-1.dll: Can' t load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" error. To solve this issue. Download a 64 bit tomcat and replace 
tcnative-1.dll
tomcat7.exe
tomcat7w.exe
files ,which are in directory xampp/tomcat/bin, with 64 bit tomcat's files.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ajaxjqjsbowling] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z
```

l0ooks like a mismatch between the version of Spring you compiled with, and the version of Spring deployed (possibly in the container). It can find the Spring class `JndiLocatorDelegate`, but not the method (i.e. the clas sitself isn't missing - just the specific method you require)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message. I am running a 64-bit version of Windows and had installed the 64-bit version of Tomcat. Anyway, for the solution I focused on the below INFO message:

> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;

When I checked my Environment Variables, I saw that `CATALINA_HOME` was set to another Tomcat path. When I changed the value to the correct path, Tomcat started successfully without an error.

**I recommend you to check all paths in your all environment variables related to Java and Tomcat**

Answer (score 0):

I had to 2 DLL's (Visual Studio) ones to get it working:
    loadLib(path, msvcr120);
    loadLib(path, msvcp120);
Used dependency walker to identify the required DLLs for your custom JNI DLL.

Comment: Can you rephrase this answer to clarify it a bit? I think you're at least missing a word where you described what you did with the two DLLs.