# Where to find 32-bit server jre for windows

Tags: java, php, tomcat

I'm trying to run php application on tomcat web server. I'm getting following error in web browser when trying to open a php page :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\php\php5servlet.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    net.php.reflect.loadLibrary(reflect.java:34)
```

On oracle website, i could not find 32-bit server jre(only [64-bit server jre](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) is available). However the website has [32-bit client jre](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), but when Tomcat points to this client jvm.dll, starting tomcat server fails.

If it is not possible to find 32-bit server jre, is it possible to find 64-bit php5servlet.dll?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse with apache tomcat, maybe this would help you with the issue. Either your eclipse not compatible or the tomcat.

[java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror can't load amd 64-bit .dll ia 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277206/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-load-amd-64-bit-dll-ia-32-bit)

So i'm guessing you have 32 bit tomcat running on 64 bit windows.
Here is the link to 64-bit tomcat
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi